# Unable to get data downloaded from Shiny app hosted on shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny

I have built a Shiny app that allows users to upload a .txt file, filter for key terms and then download the returned dataset. When hosting locally it works. However, when I deployed it to [shinyapps.io](https://www.shinyapps.io/) the download function no longer works. Everything else (e.g the data upload + wrangling step) do work. Nothing comes up as an error in the code log. The file it downloads is called 'downloadData.html' and simply says 'Please wait. Loading'. When I run and download locally it returns a .txt file (which is strange as the function is write.csv). My code is

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(rsconnect)


ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Download data"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Choose .txt file",
                multiple = F,
                accept = c(".txt")),
      textInput('energy_co', 'Name of energy company'),
      textInput('asset', 'name of Asset Manager'),
      downloadButton("downloadData", "Download")
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("table")
    )
    
  )
)


options(shiny.maxRequestSize=30*1024^2)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  company_data <- reactive({
    req(input$file1,input$asset,input$energy_co)
    
    data <- read_lines(input$file1$datapath)
    text_df <- as_data_frame(data)
    
    company_data <- text_df %>% 
      filter(str_detect(value, input$asset)) %>%   
      filter(str_detect(value, input$energy_co)) %>% 
      distinct(.)
    company_data
  })
  
  
  output$table <- renderTable({  
    
    company_data()
    
  })
  
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste(company_data(), ".csv", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      shiny::withProgress(
        message = paste0("Downloading", company_data(), " Data"),
        value = 0,
        {
          shiny::incProgress(1/10)
          Sys.sleep(1)
          shiny::incProgress(5/10)
      write.csv(company_data(), file, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )
    }
  )
  
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Does anyone have any idea how to get this to work? The code is similar (and works locally) to other related questions on SO, but unable to work out what goes wrong when hosting remotely. Nothing comes up on the app's logs.

Comment: Perhaps you should try a different name for the filename, say, `paste("mydata", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep = "")`

Comment: @YBS it didn't work unfortunately.